# Is there any physical interpretation of the refracted light in the case of total internal reflection?

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction

In the case of total internal reflection trying to obtain the angle of refraction leads to a value which cannot be represented as a real value.

$$ \sin(\theta_t) = \frac{n_1}{n_2}\sin(\theta_i) \qquad\qquad \frac{n_1}{n_2}\sin(\theta_i) > 1 \quad\to\quad \sin(\theta_t) > 1 $$

This can although be solved through the use of complex numbers. My question is then, whether there is any use to calculating this or any physical interpretation of it.

Comment: There will be an evanescent field in the second medium. Whether you can relate the imaginary $\theta_t$ to any property of the evanescent field, I'm not sure.

Comment: Evanescent fields is the reason why waveguide splitters work. Actually treating the whole EM field as complex is the way to go and those evanescent fields are also exploited (if I am not mistaken there are some beam splitters that make use of the evanescent field as well).